# How to disable toast message for Newsletter module on Odoo (v14) website

Tags: javascript, odoo, odoo-14

For the website I develop, I use Newsletter module to create a mailing list. It's quite enough for basic needs. When you insert an e-mail and click to subscribe button, it shows (replace) "Thanks" message and hide the "Subscribe" button. It also shows a toast message: "Thanks for subscribing!" on the top right side of the page.

I don't want to show toast messages for newsletter subscriptions. Unfortunately, there is no option to enable/disable it.

If I disable/remove that part below from `website_mass_mailing.js` file it doesn't show the toast message.

```
self.displayNotification({
    type: toastType,
    title: toastType === 'success' ? _t('Success') : _t('Error'),
    message: result.toast_content,
    sticky: true,
});
```

I don't want to touch this file (`website_mass_mailing.js`) but instead, inherit it and remove that part but I couldn't succeed. Any suggestion on how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After suggestions of @icra I've tried to figure it out and here is the code that worked for me.

Thanks to Cybrosys Techno Solutions Pvt.Ltd as well to achieve the solution.

Here is the code:

```
odoo.define('your_module.name', function (require){

    var publicWidget = require('web.public.widget');
    
    var _t = core._t;

    publicWidget.registry.subscribe.include({
        _onSubscribeClick: async function () {
            var self = this;
            var $email = this.$(".js_subscribe_email:visible");

            if ($email.length && !$email.val().match(/.+@.+/)) {
                this.$target.addClass('o_has_error').find('.form-control').addClass('is-invalid');
                return false;
            }
            this.$target.removeClass('o_has_error').find('.form-control').removeClass('is-invalid');
            let tokenObj = null;
            if (this._recaptcha) {
                tokenObj = await this._recaptcha.getToken('website_mass_mailing_subscribe');
                if (tokenObj.error) {
                    self.displayNotification({
                        type: 'danger',
                        title: _t("Error"),
                        message: tokenObj.error,
                        sticky: true,
                    });
                    return false;
                }
            }
            const params = {
                'list_id': this.$target.data('list-id'),
                'email': $email.length ? $email.val() : false,
            };
            if (this._recaptcha) {
                params['recaptcha_token_response'] = tokenObj.token;
            }
            this._rpc({
                route: '/website_mass_mailing/subscribe',
                params: params,
            }).then(function (result) {
                let toastType = result.toast_type;
                if (toastType === 'success') {
                    self.$(".js_subscribe_btn").addClass('d-none');
                    self.$(".js_subscribed_btn").removeClass('d-none');
                    self.$('input.js_subscribe_email').prop('disabled', !!result);
                    if (self.$popup.length) {
                        self.$popup.modal('hide');
                    }
                }

                // make the changes you need accordingly or comment out the below code.
                self.displayNotification({
                    type: toastType,
                    title: toastType === 'success' ? _t('Success') : _t('Error'),
                    message: result.toast_content,
                    sticky: true,
                });
            });
        },

    })

})
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create a new module which depends on `website_mass_mailing` and extends `mass_mailing.website_integration` via a dedicated javascript module.

For example:

```
odoo.define('my_module.mass_mailing_website_integration', function (require) {
  var website_integration = require('mass_mailing.website_integration');
  website_integration.extend({
    // Your Logic Here
  });
}
```

Find `mass_mailing` method who's calling `displayNotification` and override it.
Unfortunately i see no alternative to copy-pasting it entirely from [source](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/addons/website_mass_mailing/static/src/js/website_mass_mailing.js) and then removing desired behaviours.

Do not forget to include your javascript in `web_assets` template.

Comment: Hi @icra. After I posted this question here, I also tried to replace `website_mass_mailing.js` file, entirely copying it and comment out/remove the part that I mentioned above. In this way it works, true, but I didn't want to override the whole JS file. So I wanted to extended but I still couldn't solve how to do that.

I was also playing to extend it but couldn't succeed it. Thanks for your answer though.

Comment: As i said in my answer, only solution is to override it through a new module which injects a javascript file which overrides the method calling `displayNotification` function.

Comment: In order to extend, you must use my code example. Then define the methods you intend to override inside extend function's Object argument

Comment: icra, thank you for the answer. It really helped me. The only thing that I couldn't succeed it with is the example you provided. I got some error and I'm going to post in a new answer the version that is worked for me.